# How to send Base64 encoded image to server inside Body of Retrofit POST method

Tags: android-studio, post, bitmap, base64, retrofit2

**My onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {



        if (data.getData() == null) {
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            resultImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                resultImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Converting the "bitmap" to "Base64"**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    String convertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("CONVERT IMAGE : ", "" + convertImage);
```

**API call**

> Content-Type :application/json

```
JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
 paramObject.put("file", convertImage); //Base64 image
 paramObject.put("userName", name);

Call<Response> addImage = apiInterface.AddImage( user,  paramObject.toString());
```

**POST method**

```
@POST("{user}/image")
Call<Response> AddImage( @Path("user") String user, @Body String body);
```

**Converted image - log result**

```
E/CONVERT IMAGE :: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAAB4CAIAAAD6wG44AAAAA3NCSV...
```

**But i need to pass my Base64 string as below, my string missing the data part**

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAATIAAAExCAY......

What is the Problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just append `data:image/png;base64,` at the begining

```
 JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
 paramObject.put("file", "data:image/png;base64,"+convertImage); 
 paramObject.put("userName", name);    
 Call<Response> addImage = apiInterface.AddImage( user,  paramObject.toString());
```